# Unable to deploy maven project on payara server (Eclipse)

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, payara

I had been working on a project that involves payara server. There are 3 elements that I need to create/edit, controller, dao, service. Dao is the entity bean and service is the utility bean. After creating dao and service bean, I am unable to run the project. This error occurs:

`cannot Deploy testtest
deploy is failing=Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'BRCMBuildsheetDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.webutility.dao.BRCMBuildsheetDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.webutility.dao.BRCMBuildsheetProcess column: brcm_buildsheet_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false"). Please see server.log for more details.`

Edit: 
Thanks for pointing out the possible areas of error to me.

This is my BRCMBuildsheetDao.java

package com.webutility.dao;

```
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Order;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;


@Repository
@Transactional
@Component("BRCMBuildsheetDao")


public class BRCMBuildsheetDao {



    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Session session() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }



    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<BRCMBuildsheet> getAllBuildsheet(){
        Criteria crit = session().createCriteria(BRCMBuildsheet.class);
        crit.addOrder(Order.desc("id"));

        List<BRCMBuildsheet> list = (List<BRCMBuildsheet>) crit.list();
        System.out.println(list.size());
        return list;
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    public List<BRCMBuildsheetAssemblyLocations> getAllBuildsheetAssemblyLocation(){
        Criteria crit = session().createCriteria(BRCMBuildsheet.class);
        crit.addOrder(Order.desc("brcm_buildsheet_assembly_locations_id"));
        return (List<BRCMBuildsheetAssemblyLocations>)crit.list();
    }

}


This is my BRCMBuildsheetProcess.java


package com.webutility.dao;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "brcm_buildsheet", catalog = "b2b")
public class BRCMBuildsheetProcess {

    // primary key
    @Id
    @Column(name = "brcm_buildsheet_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int brcm_buildsheet_process_id;

    // foreign key
    // foreign key adjoining
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL,
            CascadeType.PERSIST })
    // for table that contains foreign key and stands on many relation end
    @JoinColumn(name = "brcm_buildsheet_id")
    private BRCMBuildsheet/* change to BRCMBuildsheet */buildsheet; // reference

    @Column
    private String process_type; // not sure if String or int

    @Column
    private String system_sites;

    @Column
    private String frequency_mhz;

    @Column
    private String io;

    @Column
    private String vector_memory_mb;

    @Column
    private String scan_memory_mb;

    @Column
    private String instruments;

    @Column
    private String power_supplies;

    @Column
    private String licenses;

    @Column
    private String modifier;

    @Column
    private String test_program_directory;

    @Column
    private String test_program_rev;

    @Column
    private String tester_os_rev;

    @Column
    private String switch_test_option_loadfile;

    @Column
    private String chipmon_directory;

    @Column
    private String good_time;

    @Column
    private String test_temperature_c;

    @Column
    private String text;

    @Column
    private String broadcom_legacy_spec_no;

    @Column
    private String parameter_file;

    @Column
    private String cime_file;

    @Column
    private String vector_files;

    @Column
    private String hardware_profile;

    @Column
    private String adaptor_board;

    @Column
    private String change_kit;

    @Column
    private String contractor;

    @Column
    private String custom_dut_board;

    @Column
    private String daughter_board;

    @Column
    private String mother_board;

    @Column
    private String power_personality_board;

    @Column
    private String probe_card;

    @Column
    private String probe_interface_board;

    @Column
    private String tower_interface;

    @Column
    private String prober;

    @Column
    private String handler;

    @Column
    private String test_program_flowid;

    @Column
    private String test_program_auditid;

    @Column
    private String prr;

    // //

    public int getBrcm_buildsheet_process_id() {

        return brcm_buildsheet_process_id;

    }

    public void setBrcm_buildsheet_process_id(int rcm_buildsheet_process_id) {

        this.brcm_buildsheet_process_id = rcm_buildsheet_process_id;

    }

    // //

    public BRCMBuildsheet getBRCMBuildsheet() {
        return this.buildsheet;
    }

    public void setBRCMBuildsheet(BRCMBuildsheet buildsheet) {
        this.buildsheet = buildsheet;
    }

    // ///
    public String getProcess_type() {

        return this.process_type;
    }

    public void setProcess_type(String process_type) {
        this.process_type = process_type;
    }

    // //

    public String getSystem_sites() {
        return this.system_sites;

    }

    public void setSystem_sites(String System_sites) {

        this.system_sites = System_sites;
    }

    // /

    public String getFrequency_mhz() {

        return this.frequency_mhz;

    }

    public void setFrequency_mhz(String frequency_mhz) {
        this.frequency_mhz = frequency_mhz;

    }

    ////

    public String getIo(){
        return this.io;
    }

    public void setIo(String io){

        this.io  = io;
    }

    ////

    public String getVector_memory_mb(){
        return this.vector_memory_mb;
    }

    public void setVector_memory_mb(String vector_memory_mb){
         this.vector_memory_mb = vector_memory_mb;
    }
    ////


    public String getScan_memory_mb(){
        return this.scan_memory_mb;
    }

    public void setScan_memory_mb(String scan_memory_mb){
        this.scan_memory_mb = scan_memory_mb;
    }



    ////

    public String getInstruments(){
        return this.instruments;
    }

    public void setInstruments(String instruments){
        this.instruments = instruments;
    }

    /////

    public String getPower_supplies(){

        return this.power_supplies;
    }
////    
    public String getLicenses(){return this.licenses;}
    public void setLicenses(String licenses){this.licenses = licenses;}

    public String getModifier(){return this.modifier;}
    public void setModifier(String modifier){this.modifier = modifier;}

    ////
    public String getTest_program_directory(){return this.test_program_directory;}
    public void setTest_program_directory(String test_program_directory){this.test_program_directory = test_program_directory;}
////
    public String getTest_program_rev(){return test_program_rev;}
    public void set(String test_program_rev){this.test_program_rev = test_program_rev;}
////

    public String getTester_os_rev(){ return tester_os_rev;}
    public void setTester_os_rev(String tester_os_rev){ tester_os_rev = tester_os_rev;}


/////////
    public String getSwitch_test_option_loadfile(){return this.switch_test_option_loadfile;}
    public void setSwitch_test_option_loadfile(String switch_test_option_loadfile){this.switch_test_option_loadfile = switch_test_option_loadfile;}


/////
    public String getChipmon_directory(){return this.chipmon_directory;}
    public void setChipmon_directory(String Chipmon_directory){this.chipmon_directory = chipmon_directory;}

//////
    public String getGood_time(){return this.good_time;}
    public void setGood_time(String good_time){this.good_time = good_time;}
///////////////
    public String getTest_temperature_c(){return this.test_temperature_c;}
    public void setTest_temperature_c(){}
///////////////////////////

    public String getText(){return this.text;}
    public void setText(String text ){this.text = text;} 
/////
    public String getBroadcom_legacy_spec_no(){return this.broadcom_legacy_spec_no;}

    public void setBroadcom_legacy_spec_no(String broadcom_legacy_spec_no){
        this.broadcom_legacy_spec_no = broadcom_legacy_spec_no;
    }
//////

    public String getParameter_file(){return this.parameter_file;}
    public void setParameter_file(String parameter_file){this.parameter_file = parameter_file;}

    public String getCime_file(){return this.cime_file;}
    public void setCime_file(String cime_file){this.cime_file = cime_file;}
////////////
    public String getVector_files(){return vector_files;}
    public void setVector(String vector_files){this.vector_files = vector_files;}

    //////

    public String getHardware_profile(){ return this.hardware_profile;}
    public void setHardware_profile(String hardware_profile){this.hardware_profile = hardware_profile;}
////
    public String getAdaptor_board(){return this.adaptor_board;}
    public void setAdaptor_board(String adaptor_board){adaptor_board = adaptor_board;}
////
    public String getChange_kit(){return this.change_kit;}
    public void setChange_kit(String change_kit){this.change_kit = change_kit;}

/////////
    public String getContractor(){return this.contractor;}
    public void setContractor(String contractor){this.contractor = contractor;}

    //////////////////////
    public String getCustom_dut_board(){return this.custom_dut_board;}
    public void setCustom_dut_board(String custom_dut_board){this.custom_dut_board = custom_dut_board;}


    //////////////////

    public String getDaughter_board(){return this.daughter_board;}
    public void setDaughter_board(String daughter_board){this.daughter_board = daughter_board;}
//////////////////////////

    public String getMother_board(){return this.mother_board;}
    public void setMother_board(String mother_board ){ this.mother_board = mother_board;}
///////////
    public String getPower_personality_board(){return this.power_personality_board;}
    public void setPower_personality_board(String power_personality_board){this.power_personality_board = power_personality_board;}
/////

    public String getProbe_card(){return this.probe_card;}

    public void setProbe_card(String probe_card){this.probe_card = probe_card;}

    public String getProbe_interface_board(){return this.probe_interface_board;}
    public void setProbe_interface_board(String probe_interface_board){this.probe_interface_board = probe_interface_board;}

    public String getTower_interface(){return this.tower_interface;}
    public void setTower_interface(String tower_interface){this.tower_interface = tower_interface;}

    public String getHandler(){return this.handler;}
    public void setHandler(String handler){this.handler = handler;}

    public String getTest_program_flowid(){return this.test_program_flowid;}
    public void setTest_program_flowid(String test_program_flowid){ this.test_program_flowid = test_program_flowid;}

    public String getTest_program_auditid(){return this.test_program_auditid;}
    public void setTest_program_auditid(String test_program_auditid){this.test_program_auditid = test_program_auditid;}

    public String getPrr(){return this.prr;}
    public void setPrr(String prr){this.prr = prr;}



}
```

This my root-context.xml class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web     
components -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.webutility.dao" />
<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager2"
    mode="proxy" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager3"
    mode="proxy" />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://10.58.8.200:5432/workflow" />
    <property name="username" value="poweruser" />
    <property name="password" value="pwr764usr" />
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory"
           class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="jdbc.batch_size">10000</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.webutility.dao</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<!-- ******************** -->
<bean id="dataSource2"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://10.58.8.22:5432/cim" />
    <property name="username" value="poweruser" />
    <property name="password" value="pwr764usr" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager2"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory2"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="jdbc.batch_size">10000</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.webutility.dao</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- ******************** -->

<bean id="dataSource3"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://10.58.189.41:5432/rdata" />
    <property name="username" value="readonly" />
    <property name="password" value="rdnly7543" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager3"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource3"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory3"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource3" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="jdbc.batch_size">10000</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.webutility.dao</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- ******************** -->
```

Comment: Did you look server.log for more details ?

Comment: please share the `BRCMBuildsheetDao` class and your ` application context xml`

Comment: Okay, I will share the BRCMBuildsheetDao and application context xml. I have checked and couldn't find out anything wrong about it.

Comment: This is more related to the Spring framework than to Payara Server

Comment: 'Repeated column in mapping for entity' see this error in your stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

The deploy is failing because of issues within either the entity class `com.webutility.dao.BRCMBuildsheetDao` or `com.webutility.dao.BRCMBuildsheetProcess` .

The last line clearly says :

`Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.webutility.dao.BRCMBuildsheetProcess column: brcm_buildsheet_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")`

Please make sure that you have no two columns repeated in the mapping. You might have mapped the same database column twice

Would you be able to share the code of both these entity classes